# necesito capturar los datos de los select para hacer una consulta mysql con ellos y mostrar el resultado en una tabla

Tags: html, mysql, select

```
 <?php
                include_once 'rutas.php';
                $host = "localhost";
                $user = "root";
                $pass = "";
                $bd = "freire";

                $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, '', $bd) or die("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
                $db = mysqli_select_db($con, $bd)or die("Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

                $query = "select * from conductores ";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

                $query1= "SELECT busid FROM conductores ";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1) or die("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

                $query2= "SELECT origen FROM conductores ";
                $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

                $query3= "SELECT destino FROM conductores ";
                $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $query3) or die("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

                  //$sql = "select {$variable} from rio where fecha_muestra>={$fecha_muestra1} and fecha_muestra<={$fecha_muestra2}";
                $consulta= "SELECT ventaT,totalP,billetesV,ingresoT FROM tabla ";               
                $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $consulta) or die("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
                mysqli_close($con);
                ?>
                <?php 

                ?>
             <!--<form method="post" action="rutas.php">-->
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <label>Conductor:</label>
                        <select name="conductor" id="conductor" class="form-group">
                            <option value="0">---seleccione---</option>
                             <?php
                                while ($lista = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
                                      <option value = " <?php echo $lista['nombre']; ?> "><?php echo $lista['nombre']; ?></option> 

                                <?php } ?>

                        </select>    

                        <label>Número Bus :</label>
                        <select name="bus" id="bus" class="form-group">
                            <option value="0">---seleccione---</option>
                              <?php
                                while ($li = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){  ?>
                                 <option value = " <?php echo $li['busid']; ?> "><?php echo $li['busid']; ?></option> 

                                <?php } ?>                      
                        </select>


                        <label> Parada Origen:</label>
                        <select name="origen" id="origen" class="form-group">
                            <option value="0">---seleccione---</option>
                                 <?php
                                while ($li = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){  ?>
                                      <option value = " <?php echo $li['origen']; ?> "><?php echo $li['origen']; ?></option> 

                                <?php } ?>                   
                        </select>


                        <label>Parada Destino:</label>
                        <select name="destino" id="destino" class="form-group">
                            <option value="0">---seleccione---</option>

                            <?php                                                    
                                while ($li = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){  ?>
                                    <option value = " <?php echo $li['destino']; ?> "><?php echo $li['destino']; ?></option> 

                                <?php } ?>                       
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <script>
   function buscar() {
       var conductor = document.getElementById("conductor").value;
       var bus = document.getElementById("bus").value;
       var origen = document.getElementById("origen").value;
       var destino = document.getElementById("destino").value;
       alert(bus);
       alert(conductor);
       alert(origen);
       alert(destino);

}
</script>
                    <button type="button" name="buscar"  onclick="buscar()" class="btn btn-info">Buscar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button> 


                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnExport" value=" Export Excel " >Export Excel <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span></button>


                </div>                    


                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="dvData" class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="exportTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

                            <thead>
                                <tr class="danger">
                                    <th>Venta Taquilla</th>
                                    <th>Total Pasajeros</th>
                                    <th>Billetes Vendidos </th>
                                    <th>Ingreso Total</th>                                        
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <?php
                                    while ($datos = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo $datos["ventaT"] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $datos["totalP"] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $datos["billetesV"] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $datos["ingresoT"] ?></td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
             <footer><p>Copyright © 2017: <a href="http://empresafreire.com">Empresa Freire S.L.</a></p></footer>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: De verdad se supone que tenemos que hacerle ingeniería inversa a ese código y tratar de ver cómo se relaciona con el título de la pregunta?

Comment: Edita la pregunta, empieza por contarnos qué quieres hacer, qué tienes y qué no te resulta. Y no pongas todo el código, no sabemos dónde exactamente habria que mirar

Comment: jaja vale tengo este select y kiero capturar su value pero con $var=$_POST['origen']; no me funciona
     <select name="origen" id="origen" class="form-group">
                                <option value="0">---seleccione---</option>
                                     <?php                                while ($li = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){  ?>
                                          <option value = " <?php echo $li['origen']; ?> "><?php echo $li['origen']; ?></option>                                           
                                    <?php } ?>          </select>

Comment: Pon eso en la pregunta, los comentarios no resaltan sintaxis

Answer (score 1):

No veo problema en tu código, salvo que has comentado el elemento `form`,  lo cual podría ser problemático si quieres enviar los datos contenidos en un formulario que no es tal.

De todos modos escribo esta respuesta para indicar algunas cosas:

1. Siempre que vayas a manipular elementos del DOM, haz referencia a ellos desde una función que evalúe el estado de `DOMContentLoaded`... Si intentas usar un elemento sin que el DOM termine de cargarse, no encontrarás dicho elemento y el código fallará.
2. Yo no pondría la función dentro del botón, sino que le daría un id al botón y escucharía los clicks de ese botón en JS mediante su id. De ese modo tu HTML es un poco más independiente.

El código debería funcionar. He aquí una prueba.

```js
/*Se recomienda llamar  esta función  
 *para asegurar que los elementos del DOM están disponibles
 *dentro de ella se deben manipular todos los elementos del DOM*/
 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

 var btnBuscar = document.getElementById("btnBuscar");
        btnBuscar.onclick  = buscar;

});


function buscar() {
/*
  var conductor = document.getElementById("conductor").value;
  var bus = document.getElementById("bus").value;
  var destino = document.getElementById("destino").value;
  alert(bus);
  alert(conductor);
  alert(destino);
*/

  var origen = document.getElementById("idorigen").value;
  alert("Seleccionaste el origen: "+origen);

}
```

```html
<form id="frm" method="post" action="rutas.php">
  <label> Parada Origen:</label>
  <select name="origen" id="idorigen" class="form-group">
      <option value="0">---seleccione---</option>
      <option value="1">Origen 1</option>
      <option value="2">Origen 2</option>
      <option value="3">Origen 3</option>
      </select>
  <button id="btnBuscar">Buscar</button>
</form>
```